# Можно ли пользоваться Xdebug?

Tags: php, отладка, xdebug

Есть PhpStorm но локальная копия проекта, но на компах разработчиков нет веб-серверов и сразу после внесения изменений всё моментально летит на dev-сервер и сразу там тестируется.

Можно ли в таких условиях пользоваться Xdebug или какими-то другими продвинутыми системами отладки? Если Xdebug на dev-сервер поставить можно ли будет его как-то связать с IDE в данном случае?

Или в конфиге к шторму можно удалённый сервер прописывать, например `xdebug.remote_host=85.69.66.104`?

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug будет подключаться по адресу который указан в настройках. Если у вас несколько разработчиков хотят одновременно отлаживать приложение необходимо им локально разворачивать сервер с xdebug. В этой ситуации XDebug выступает клиентом и подключается к серверу(PhpStorm).